# Is it possible to make a landline voice call from a mobile connected by wifi to all-in-one box?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, voip

I pay my Internet Service Provider for internet access and landline telephone. He’s provided me with a phone number plus one of those all-in-one connect boxes that contains a modem, a router exposing several RJ45 to connect computers, a WiFi and a RJ11 to connect a standard phone.

When the box came in, I had to plug it to the wall, to a digital wire installed by my provider. Then I turned on the box, then I waited 1 minute for it to configure itself, and then it was ready to use.

As far as I know (which is little), the RJ11 plug should be connected to a PABX-IP converter, which can access a remote VOIP-Server via the Router, the Modem, and Internet.

I’ve drawn a little schema to illustrate this:

[image: The all-in-one box contains a IP-PABX, a WiFi, a Router and a Modem]

This is my question: Can I use a smartphone, or a soft-phone, connected to the WiFi, to make and receive calls using my landline phone number?

If yes, how? I guess I would need to configure it with VOIP Server‘s endpoint. If no, why?

Comment: What kind of PABX-IP converter? I would assume that's where the VoIP connections are initiated from. Have you tried asking the ISP about it?

Comment: @grawity I don't know the kind of PABX-IP converter because it is in the all-in-one box. I agree with you; it's where the VoIP connections are initiated from. My first step was to ask my ISP. They confirmed that my phone is internally a VoIP, but refuse to give me any further details. They didn't even confirmed or denied that there is a VoIP server somewhere.

Comment: Not knowing anything about the VoIP/PABX box this is only just barely about a "home networking" device and does not involve computer hardware or software in any way that is compatible with our site rules. This is a "black box" device configured and controlled by your ISP and only they can tell you what you can do with it. Smartphones are off topic here.